# Animate color property with different brushes

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following in a `ControlTemplate.Resources`:

```
<ColorAnimation
    Storyboard.TargetName="border"
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
    To="Orange"
    Duration="0:0:0.2" />
```

It works all right if the original background that I wanted to change to orange was a solid color. But I'd also want to have this work when the original background is a `LinearGradientBrush`. In this second case, the animation tries to change the property in vain, nothing happens.

How can I specify an animation that replaces the background no matter what type it was earlier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `Background` is `LinearGradientBrush`, then you will have to animate each `GradientStop` to the `Color` you want i.e. Orange in this case:

```
      <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="Orange"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="Orange"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

But if you want to `Animate` the whole `Brush` irrespective of its type then you will have to create your own Animation. I have created my own BrushAnimation class to animate the Brush

```
    public class BrushAnimation : AnimationTimeline
    {
        static BrushAnimation()
        {
            FromProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("From", typeof(Brush),
                typeof(BrushAnimation),new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush()));

            ToProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("To", typeof(Brush),
                typeof(BrushAnimation), new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush()));
        }

        public override Type TargetPropertyType
        {
            get
            {
                return typeof(Brush);
            }
        }

        protected override System.Windows.Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
        {
            return new BrushAnimation();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FromProperty;
        public Brush From
        {
            get
            {
                return (Brush)GetValue(BrushAnimation.FromProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(BrushAnimation.FromProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ToProperty;
        public Brush To
        {
            get
            {
                return (Brush)GetValue(BrushAnimation.ToProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(BrushAnimation.ToProperty, value);
            }
        }


        public override object GetCurrentValue(object defaultOriginValue,
            object defaultDestinationValue, AnimationClock animationClock)
        {
            Brush fromVal = ((Brush)GetValue(BrushAnimation.FromProperty));
            Brush toVal = ((Brush)GetValue(BrushAnimation.ToProperty));

            SolidColorBrush solid = toVal as SolidColorBrush;

            if(fromVal is LinearGradientBrush)
            {
                LinearGradientBrush brush = fromVal as LinearGradientBrush;
                LinearGradientBrush newBrush = new LinearGradientBrush();
                foreach(var stop in brush.GradientStops)
                {
                    ColorAnimation animation = new ColorAnimation(stop.Color,solid.Color,this.Duration);
                    Color color = animation.GetCurrentValue(stop.Color, solid.Color, animationClock);
                    newBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(color,stop.Offset));
                }

                return newBrush;
            }
            else
            {
                SolidColorBrush brush = fromVal as SolidColorBrush;
                SolidColorBrush newsolid = new SolidColorBrush();
                ColorAnimation solidAnimation = new ColorAnimation(brush.Color, solid.Color, this.Duration);
                newsolid.Color = solidAnimation.GetCurrentValue(brush.Color, solid.Color, animationClock);

                return newsolid;

            }

        }
```

and I am using this Animation to animate Canvas.Background on my window

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="MyStoryBoard" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True">
        <local:BrushAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Canvas1"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty = "(Canvas.Background)" 
                        To="Orange" Duration="0:0:5"/>
    </Storyboard>
```

and you can set `From` property of animation using the StaticResource or set it to the Background of Control in your codebehind like:

```
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ((BrushAnimation) ((Storyboard) Resources["SolidStoryBoard"]).Children[0]).From = Canvas1.Background;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what it is. It's a button that might have either kind of background.

Comment: I have created the animation class to handle this. Tested it.. works well :)